# AOL sluggish on new MacBook Pro

Tags: macos

I have New MacBook Pro, 13". Transferred everything from my PowerBook G4. Now my AOL (v. 10.3) is performing sluggishly. Namely, it takes 75 seconds to quit. Everything freezes in the interim. Any ideas?

Comment: Dude, it's AOL. Who still uses AOL?

Comment: What is the exact subversion (e.g. 10.3.6, 10.3.7, etc.?)? Also, have you considered dropping AOL altogether in favor of just using a browser? AOL does not focus on supporting its browsers any more -- they are getting out of that business and focusing on their web-based applications and content.

Comment: I thought AOL was dead? :P

Answer (score 3):

Going from a G4 to a new Macbook means you've moved to Leopard / Snow Leopard. Your older version of AOL is probably not Leopard compatible. [AOL Desktop v1.5](http://daol.aol.com/software/mac) is available and claims to be Leopard compatible.

But really, AOL? In the 2010s?!

(I notice no one's using the new "Aol." wording :-)